# How to have authorize.net send confirmation email

Tags: c#, asp.net, credit-card, authorize.net

I am doing a checkout page and implemented authorize.net's c# sample code:

[Code Here](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-csharp/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/ChargeCreditCard.cs)

Client wants to have authorize.net send a confirmation email.
I am having a hard time finding how to do that in the documentation. How do you do this on the code end?

Comment: I just did a quick search of AuthorizeNet documentation and didn't find anything regarding sending email.  Is there a reason you don't want to use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?

Comment: Client preference.  I was told authorize.net does do this service and to look into how to do it.

Comment: Did you look in their Implementation Guide at http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf?  In the TransactionResponse section they describe how to do email receipts.

Comment: I'm confused on AIM, I've seen those acronyms and others used but the sample code doesn't address it.  But I did find in their documentation "Our AIM API has provided a secure, robust and reliable integration for many years. We continue to support the AIM API, but we encourage developers to use our Authorize.Net API, which provides a consistent programming interface across all our feature set (AIM only supports payment transactions)."  https://developer.authorize.net/api/upgrade_guide/

Answer (score 0):

net will send the mail to customer all you need do is check the check box in the settings in account tab.The following is the path for it

account tab==> Email Receipt ==>fist check box in the page

Here i am attaching the screenshot for above 
[Step 1 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDQkH.png)
Step 2: 
[Step 2 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsdvm.png)